# How do I make a function that recognizes text?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this textbox where you can paste a large block of text into it and it will output the number of lines of text. However, it only works after a single key is pressed into the box. So if I right click and hit "paste" then it won't display the number of lines until I press a key on my keyboard.
How can I just make it automatically display the number of lines upon pasting the text?

Here's my current code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style type="text/css">
textarea {
    border: 0 none white;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    background-color: #D0D0D0;
    resize: none;
}
</style>

<script>

function countLines(theArea)
{
  var theLines = theArea.value.replace((new RegExp(".{"+theArea.cols+"}","g")),"\n").split("\n");

  if(theLines[theLines.length-1]=="")
  theLines.length--;
  theArea.form.lineCount.value = theLines.length;
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
var observe;
if (window.attachEvent) 
{
    observe = function (element, event, handler) 
    {
        element.attachEvent('on'+event, handler);
    };
}
else 
{
    observe = function (element, event, handler)
    {
        element.addEventListener(event, handler, false);
    };
}
function init ()
{
    var text = document.getElementById('text');
    function resize () 
    {
        text.style.height = 'auto';
        text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
    }
    /* 0-timeout to get the already changed text */
    function delayedResize ()
    {
        window.setTimeout(resize, 0);
    }
    observe(text, 'change',  resize);
    observe(text, 'cut',     delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'paste',   delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'drop',    delayedResize);
    observe(text, 'keydown', delayedResize);

    text.focus();
    text.select();
    resize();
}


</script>

</head>

<body onload="init();">
<form>


<textarea rows="5" cols="40" style="height:1em;" id="text"; name="myText" onKeyUp="countLines(this)">

</textarea>


<br>
Cost: <input type=text name="lineCount" size="1" value="0"> Dollars

</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Well, _change_ is challenging for some people.

Comment: you need a `Javascript` or `jQuery`

Comment: @Ljubisa I guess it could be done with html as #Sly pointed

Comment: @user689, one would need more than HTML to accomplish this. Cheers.

Comment: so i can't do it with javascript?

Comment: @Sly the guy used javascript as you see in his code, but his problemis in calling the function when he pastes the text, which could be done with html only.

Comment: @user689, a very simple implementation of jQuery and a change event for the text field would solve the problem. If _you_ can do what he's asking _only_ using HTML, please show me. The jQuery implementation would be cleaner and more elegant than inline onChange calls. Cheers.

Comment: @user689, I did, but I think you missed the point I was trying to get at.  Please reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5871640/why-is-using-onclick-in-html-a-bad-practice

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you are using the keyup function. Remember the user is pasting the text and not pressing any key.
`<textarea rows="5" cols="40" style="height:1em;" id="text"; name="myText" onchange="countLines(this)">`

Use the onchange attribute, which occurs when the value of the text area is changed.

Note: as @Sly pointed doing this in javascript is more recommended:

`$("textarea").change(function(){ //your function here}`

[Or even better](http://api.jquery.com/change/)

Comment: @user3192299 try using javascript(jquery) instead!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell it to change when something happens. If you have done this already, edit your question to say so.

I imagine your code looks something like:

```
<textarea onchange="your_function();">

</textarea>
```

Now, if you have done that and it's not working, then I would suggest running it every few seconds.

In your Javascript, if that's what you're using, then use this code:

```
window.setInterval(your_function, time_in_miliseconds)
```

Comment: I think you mean `window.setInterval(your_function, time_in_miliseconds)` ;)

Comment: Thanks... that would be a question that I would have to post on here 'cause I'm just that awesome and forget that you don't have to do the ().

Comment: It would be safe to put it directly after your function, or at the very top. However, I don't know too incredibly much about Javascript, so I would need someone to back me up on the "put it at the top" part. If it was me, I would put it right after the function.

Comment: I added it but the function still won't work. It only works on OnKeyUp but OnChange doesn't do anything. I put this at the end of the function:

    window.setInterval(countLines(this), 1)

Comment: You're doing it wrong. Put it in your code. Not when you call it in "onchange".